# Programmatically obtaining files content data (copied in local clipboard) in remote desktop session

Tags: winapi, clipboard, rdp

Here is what i need to do:

1. User opens a remote desktop session (RD Web Access / Remote apps)
2. User copies files from explorer (CTRL+C) on local PC
3. User clicks on a button in our app (running in the RD session) and files are copied (pasted) to a known directory on the server

The copy/paste operation works flawlessly when manually done in remote file explorer but when programmatically accessing clipboard content from the remote session all I can get is the file list (without local paths) via the "FileGroupDescriptorW" Format.

I am aware this is normal and have read the MSN "RDP - Clipboard Virtual Channel Extension" Doc.

I think the only solution would be to request the files content using a "Format Contents Request PDU" and "Format Contents Response PDU" from the Clipboard Virtual Channel.

Problem is I have no Idea how to implement this in Delphi (or any other language as I have been unable to find any code sample for this on the web)

So how can I programmatically access the Clipboard Virtual Channel from the RD Session and stream the files content? Code samples would be greatly appreciated (even more if there are in Pascal/Delphi)

Thanks !

Comment: Personally I think you'd be better keeping this language neutral and making it a pure winapi question, thereby attracting a wider audience

Comment: I have changed tags to follow your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced (and solved) this problem with a small vb script.

This script can be generated and launched by your Delphi App.

*My_Destination\Folder* is the destination folder, *Folder* is the name of the destination windows that opens and *Copying...* is the name of the progress-bar windows showing while copying the files.

```
Set objshell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objshell.Run "cmd.exe /C start " & "My_Destination\Folder"


success = objshell.AppActivate("My_Destination\Folder")
WScript.Sleep 500

objshell.Sendkeys "%HV"

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WScript.Sleep 3000
Do 
   If (oShell.AppActivate("Copying...") = False) Then
      If oShell.AppActivate("Folder") Then
         WScript.Sleep 500
         oShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
      End If
      WScript.Sleep 3000
      Exit Do
   Else
      WScript.Sleep 3000
   End If
Loop
```

The first lines opens an Explorer window of the destination folder.
Once the windows is activated, you can send keystrokes emulating a paste operation (Paste: %HV).

The last part waits the termination of the copy operation and then closes the opened windows.

Note: *Copying...* window-name and keystroke sequences (*%HV*) are language dependent.